# Removing characters from filename in batch

Tags: python, batch-file

I have 3 main folder in Windows explorer that contain files with naming like this  ALB_01_00000_intsect_d.kml or Baxters_Creek_AL_intsect_d.kml. Even though the first name changes the consistent thing that I would like to remove from all these files is "_intsect_d". Would like to do this for all files within each of the folders. The files have an extension .kml. The result I am expecting as per the example above is ALB_01_00000.kml and the other one would be 
Baxters_Creek_AL.kml. Dont know much about programming in python, but would like help to write a script that can acheive the result mentioned above. Thanks

Comment: Please review this question - it might be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297468/removing-characters-from-filename-in-batch

Answer (score 19):

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir('dirname'):
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace('_intsect_d', ''))
```

Comment: if you get error `The system cannot find the file specified` then change your `os.chdir` cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/48947477/3154274

Comment: ```import os
path = r"C:\shared_data\results_anat\20211122_1322_OldMatching"
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    new_filename = filename.replace('20211122_1322_', '')
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, new_filename))```

Answer (score 3):

This code can be used to remove any particular character or set of characters recursively from all filenames within a directory and replace them with any other character, set of characters or no character.

```
import os

paths = (os.path.join(root, filename)
        for root, _, filenames in os.walk('C:\FolderName')
        for filename in filenames)

for path in paths:
    # the '#' in the example below will be replaced by the '-' in the filenames in the directory
    newname = path.replace('#', '-')
    if newname != path:
        os.rename(path, newname)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on nicholas's solution, but that code breaks if any of the folder names contain the character you want to replace.

For instance, if you want to `newname = path.replace('_', '')` but your path looks like `/path/to/data_dir/control_43.csv` you will get an `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
#to get directory path you are in now
os.getcwd()
#you will see you'r not at the same path of your files 
#you must change your path to folder having your files 
os.chdir('''/the_folder_path ''')
#then you will use this 
for filename in os.listdir('''/your_folder_path'''):
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace('what_you_need_to_replace', 'your_change'))
```

this work in macOS I think in windows you need to use // in directory path