# Python - WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, filenames

I have a folder full of pdf files. I'm trying to remove all the spaces from files name and replace them with underscores. Here's what I have so far:

```
import os, sys

folder = path to folder
FileList = os.listdir(folder)

for files in FileList:
    if ' ' in files:
        NewName = files.replace(" ", "_")
        os.rename(files, NewName)
```

When I run this script I get the following error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I'm guessing there is a pretty simple fix, but I've look all over and cannot find a solution for the life of me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `cwd/folder/file` cannot be found in `cwd/file`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

...

```
os.rename(os.path.join(folder, files), os.path.join(folder, NewName))
```

Answer (score 2):

just change your directory to the one in which the files has to be renamed and then follow your code.

use: `os.chdir("destinationFolder")`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution for my case. I was wanting to rename files and kept getting the WindowsError: [Error 2].  Simply changing the current directory with

```
os.chdir(currdir)
```

and then not trying to work with the full path did the trick.  Here's the relevant lines of script

```
if(os.path.exists(wd)) == 0:
print(wd+" DOES NOT EXIST!!")
sys.exit()

directories = [x[0] for x in os.walk(wd)]
ld = len(directories)
dsorted = sorted(directories)
print(dsorted)

for num in range(1,ld):
    currdir = dsorted[num]
    print("Working on Directory  "+currdir)
    os.chdir(currdir)
    filenames = next(os.walk(currdir))[2]
    l = len(filenames)

    for num in range(0,l):

        name = filenames[num]
        print("Present file  "+name)
        modtime = os.path.getmtime(name);print(modtime)
        moddate =datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(modtime).strftime('%Y %m %d')
        moddate = moddate.replace(" ", "")
        print(moddate)

        namesplit = name.split(".")

        base = namesplit[0]
        newbase = base+"_"+moddate   
        newname = newbase+"."+namesplit[1]
        print(newname)       

        os.rename(name,newname)
        input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You renaming files in current directory but reading in the `folder`. You need to add to `os.rename` the folder path or at the beginning `os.chdir(folder)` and then just use `os.listdir()` and `os.rename`