# os.rename not working

Tags: python, operating-system, rename

I try to rename files. Do not want file begins with "__". Tried using code from post:
[Removing characters from filename in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297468/removing-characters-from-filename-in-batch)

When making list:

```
myDir = os.listdir(r"S:\Shared\Santa Rosa")
for x in myDir:
  ...
```

I get this output:

```
Tuesday
Wednesday
__1831.pdf
__1832.pdf
__1833.pdf
__1834.pdf
__1841.pdf
__1842.pdf
__1843.pdf
__1844.pdf
__1851.pdf
__1852.pdf
__1853.pdf
__1854.pdf
__1861.pdf
__1862.pdf
```

But when do this:

```
for x in myDir:
    os.rename(x, x.replace('__', ''))
```

I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 2, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: You'll need to prepend the entire path to your filenames... this means adding `S:\Shared\Santa Rosa` as the prefix.

Comment: To make your work a tad easier, try pathlib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: I suggest you use `glob.glob()` instead of `os.listdir` because the former will return full pathnames if you pass it one as an argument in the call. Otherwise you'll need to `os.path.join()` the parent-folder name(s) to every filename-only that the latter returns before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give the full pathname to os.rename, e.g. something like

```
dirName = r"S:\Shared\Santa Rosa"
myDir = os.listdir(dirName)
for x in myDir:
    oldName = os.path.join(dirName, x)
    newName = os.path.join(dirName, x.replace('__', ''))
    os.rename(oldName, newName)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `glob`. Use it to filter filenames. And since it returns a usable path, you don't need `os.path.join`.

```
>>> from glob import glob
>>> import os
>>> for fn in glob("tmp/__*.pdf"):
...     print(fn)
...     os.rename(fn, fn.replace("__", ""))
... 
tmp/__aaa.pdf
tmp/__bbb.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.rename()` needs the full path to the file:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(r"S:\Shared\Santa Rosa", x), os.path.join(r"S:\Shared\Santa Rosa", x.replace("__", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.path.join` to get the full path.

```
dirPath = r"S:\Shared\Santa Rosa"
myDir = os.listdir(dirPath)
for x in myDir:
   x = os.path.join(myDir, x)
   os.rename(x, x.replace('__', ''))
```