# Selecting the numerical part of batch files for renaming

Tags: python

In a directory, I have a folder with a lot of *.mp4 files that their names follow the pattern (num)_pure_hm.mp4.  The numbers are not in order.

I need to rename them and in this regard by using the solution introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24297492/11140344):

```py
import os

path_initial = '/mnt'
path_video = os.path.join(path_initial,'gazemap_videos')

for filename in os.listdir(path_video):
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace('_pure_hm', ''))
```

Although I have a file with the name of `443_pure_hm.mp4` in that folder, I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '443_pure_hm.mp4' -> '443.mp4'
File "/home/Rename.py", line 7, in <module>
os.rename(filename, filename.replace('_pure_hm', ''))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:    '443_pure_hm.mp4' -> '443.mp4'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Use the search facility to locate one of the very many similar questions already existing on this site. This is not a gimme some code type of site, and as a not new member, you should be aware of that. Please re-take the [tour], then read through the linked content within [ask] to better understand how this site should work to your benefit.

Comment: What if you have different names but same numbers, e.g. `5_able.avi`, `5_baker.avi` and `5_charlie.avi` ?

Comment: @Daweo , In this case, the numbers will not be the same.

Answer (score 3):

`os.listdir` just lists the file names. You need to somehow add the path in. E.g. using `src_dir_fd` and `dst_dir_fd`:

```py
import os

path_initial = '/mnt'
path_video = os.path.join(path_initial,'gazemap_videos')

for filename in os.listdir(path_video):
    os.rename(
        filename, 
        filename.replace('_pure_hm', ''), 
        src_dir_fd=path_video, 
        dst_dir_fd=path_video
    )
```